# How do I import images into Wagtail from a managment command?

Tags: django, wagtail

I've got a data model similar to this for storing a list of locations and a gallery of photos associated with each location:

```py
@register_snippet
class Location(modelcluster.models.ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField()

class LocationPhoto(Orderable):
    location = ParentalKey(
        Location,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='gallery'
    )

    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailImage.Image',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='+',
    )

    alt = models.CharField(verbose_name='Alt text')
```

I would like to create a management command that can load these locations and their associated galleries in bulk from a JSON file and a folder of images.

How do I, in Python, import the images so that they end up in the `media/` directory as if I had uploaded them through the Wagtail admin UI?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example assuming you have a filepath

```
from wagtail.images.models import Image
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
from io import BytesIO

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Import an image from filepath"

def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('filepath')

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    # You child will be added to the parent
    parent = YourParentObject.objects.first()
    your_object = YourObject(title="Something",...)
    if exists(options["filepath"]):
        # Open the file as binary
        with open(filepath,"rb") as imagefile:
            # Gets the name of the file
            filename = filepath.split("/")[-1]
            image = Image(file=ImageFile(BytesIO(imagefile.read()), name=filename))
            image.save()
            your_object.your_image_field = image
            # now you can save your model
    parent.add_child(instance=your_object)
```