# Can I add images from an AWS S3 bucket to Wagtail/Django database, without downloading and re-uploading each file?

Tags: python, django, image, amazon-s3, wagtail

I have a pre-existing AWS S3 bucket that I want to use for Wagtail Images. I want to populate the gallery with the images held in the S3 bucket, so that they're accessible to image fields on page models and also to RichText embedded imagery.

The issue is that there are 1500 images, so I think I want to avoid having the script actually download/open each of these files if I can help it; I'm worried it will make the script run a long time and might kill down a server with a small amount of memory.

Is there a way to register the files in the database **without actually opening each image?**

#### Where I'm up to

Where I think I'm going with this is to manually pull down the file references using boto and then somehow plug those references into the database?

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

items = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='xxx')

for item in items:
   image = CMSImage(...)
```

But what next, I'm not sure of. I see [solutions which involve downloading/opening the files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63026185/1053937), but is there a way to do this without that?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to stop Wagtail from downloading the files, as it needs to ascertain image dimensions, but I was able to stop it from uploading duplicate original imagery. With the below solution, the original S3 file keys are used by Wagtail.

(Of course, renditions are still created and added to the S3 bucket as per Wagtail's normal operations.)

Here's how I did it (with [django-storage's S3 integration](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) in the background):

- Get the django `File` instance from remote storage via Django's storage API.
- Attach that `File` from storage to a new wagtail Image instance, *after* creating the instance
- **Crucially, set `image.file._committed = True` to prevent re-upload**. This counteracts the [default logic of the FileField class to save and upload newly attached files](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2480554dc4ada4ecf3f6a08e318735a2e50783f3/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L314).

##### Code example:

```py
import boto3
from wagtail.images.models import Image

# Loop through images in an S3 bucket
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
items = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='xxx')["Contents"]

# Image sync
for item in items:
   file_name = item["Key"]
   # get a `File` instance for each image
   s3_file = default_storage.open(file_name)
   # prepare a new wagtail `Image` instance
   image = Image(title=file_name)
   # attach the `File` after `Image` instantiation
   image.file = s3_file
   # prevent re-upload
   image.file._committed = True
   # Wagtail will generate some renditions and so on, but won't re-upload the original file :)
   image.save()
```

##### Implemented in `app/management/commands/sync_s3_images.py` for execution on the server:

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import boto3
from wagtail.images.models import Image

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        items = get_images_from_s3()

        for item in items:
            file_name = item["Key"]
            if "." in file_name:
                image = save_s3_image_to_db(file_name=file_name, url=f'https://{settings.AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{file_name}')

def save_s3_image_to_db(file_name=None, url=None):
    print("Syncing", url)
    try:
        image = Image.objects.get(title=file_name)
    except Image.DoesNotExist:
        if default_storage.exists(file_name):
            # get a `File` instance for each image
            s3_file = default_storage.open(file_name)
            # prepare a new wagtail `Image` instance
            image = Image(title=file_name)
            # attach the `File` after `Image` instantiation
            image.file = s3_file
            # prevent re-upload
            image.file._committed = True
            # Wagtail will generate some renditions and so on, but won't re-upload the original file :)
            image.save()

def get_images_from_s3(**kwargs):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                             aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

    NextContinuationToken = None
    items = []

    while NextContinuationToken is not False:
        args = dict(
            Bucket=settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
            **kwargs,
        )

        if NextContinuationToken:
           args.update(dict(ContinuationToken=NextContinuationToken))

        response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(**args)
        items += response["Contents"]


        if "NextContinuationToken" in response:
            NextContinuationToken = response["NextContinuationToken"]
        else:
            NextContinuationToken = False

    return items
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for posting this answer. I will be bookmarking it for future reference!